# VBCSComplier.exe goes to 100% cpu usage on a deployed ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

We are about to go live with a new web site in ASP.NET (MVC) and noticed some delays in response time on the production server. The production system is a new Microsoft Azure VM (A2 Basic, this site will only have few users). The database is on a separate system.

Watching the CPU via resource manager we notice that VBCSComplier.exe jumps to 50% CPU usage on each core where we are just loading a static web page with couple of database checks for permissions. This jump in CPU does not happen with our desktop or test systems or in other place in the application where we generate the web page.

A search finds a few mentions issues multiple copies of VBCSCompiler running, but we only have one instance running. Others mention issues with VBCSCompiler within Visual Studio builds, but this is a deployed system.

Comment: Why are you deploying a site to a VM in Azure rather than a Web App?

Comment: We need to run a few third party apps to generate files for download. I tested the site as a Web App, but moved it to VM for the file creation functions.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Also facing the same issue - hoping for a solution

Comment: I don't have a single line of VB-code (only C#) but for some reason VBCSComplier.exe is doing "something" and using over 300MB RAM.. Insanity. I found all instances of VBCSComplier.exe (found 4 files) and renamed them to _VBCSComplier.exe. This finally stopped the madness.

Comment: I was able to reduce the amount of CPU used by VBCSCompiler after publish by disabling option "precompile during publish" in VS 2019.

Comment: Hi, anyone found the solution for this?